# Nexus functionality is limited after installation

Tags: linux, https, reverse-proxy, nexus

I have a CentOS based server with Sonatype Nexus 2.0.4-1 installed. The issue is that there are no standard "Artifact Search", "Advanced Search", "Browse Index", "Refresh Index" Nexus features, as well as Artifact Information tab after selection of any artifact (only Maven Information tab). I tried to Google, but was amazed that there're no information about this issue.

Actually it looks like all actions I've done are:

```
wget http://www.sonatype.org/downloads/nexus-2.0.4-1-bundle.tar.gz
tar -xvf nexus-2.0.4-1-bundle.tar.gz
cp -r nexus-2.0.4-1 sonatype-work /opt/
ln -s /opt/nexus-2.0.4-1/* /opt/nexus
ln /opt/nexus/bin/nexus /etc/init.d/
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/nexus 
vim /etc/init.d/nexus
NEXUS_HOME=“/opt/nexus”
RUN_AS_USER=“nexus”
useradd -s /sbin/nologin -d /var/lib/nexus nexus
chown -R nexus /opt/nexus/
chown -R nexus /opt/nexus-2.0.4-1/
sudo -u nexus cp /opt/nexus/conf/examples/proxy-https/jetty.xml /opt/nexus/conf/
```

To force Nexus be available through HTTPS I went to Administration -> Server -> Application Server Settings as admin and changed Base URL to https:// external IP/nexus and set Force Base URL to true.

Any ideas how to get missed Nexus features?